# Restrict bounded type parameter A<B> and A<C>

Tags: java, generics

I want to bind the type parameter of the child classes. Let's suppose these are the classes:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

I want to bind the above classes so if someone creating a class should only be able to pass self class name. Eg:

```
class B extends A<B> {} // valid
class C extends A<B> {} // invalid
class C extends A<C> {} // valid
```

The closest I could get to this is:

```
class A<T extends A<? super T>> {}
class B extends A<B> {}
class C extends A<B> {} // allows it, but I don't want to allow this.
```

How can this be achived?

Use case:

```
class A<T extends A<? super T>> {
    private T t;
    private A() {}
    protected A(T t) {this.t = t;}
    public T something() { return t; }
}
class B extends A<B> {
    public B(B b) {super(b);}
    public B anotherthing() { return this.something(); }
}
```

Comment: If you want that kind of restriction, why do you want to make the type generic? In what way should `A` be generic on some type?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have updated the question, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It should only allow the child class to have itself as generic type. `class B extends A<B>`, `class C extends A<C>`, `class D extends A<D>`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this at compile-time.

If you really want, you can enforce it at run-time (preventing problematic classes from being instantiated) by adding logic to `A`'s non-private constructor:

```
    protected A(T t) {
        validateClass(getClass());
        this.t = t;
    }

    private static void validateClass(final Class<?> clazz) {
        final Type superclass = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
        if ((superclass instanceof ParameterizedType)
            && ((ParameterizedType)superclass).getRawType() == A.class
            && ((ParameterizedType)superclass)getActualTypeArguments()[0] == clazz
        ) {
            // OK
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                clazz + " does not extend A<" + class.getName() + ">");
        }
    }
```

. . . but I don't think that's a great idea.

In general, although Java provides lots of features for compile-time protections, a Java program ultimately relies on developers to voluntarily write correct code. Many aspects of class contracts are documented, but not enforced. (For example, nothing forces the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods to be consistent with each other; but if you're writing Java code, you'll read the documentation of those methods before overriding them, so will know what you need to do.) In your case, you're best off just telling developers that subclasses of `A` should pass themselves as the type argument to `A`, giving them an example, and trusting them to do it.